# Screencast on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, screencast

I'm trying to make a screencast in Ubuntu 11.10.
I need to insert some text for explaining all the steps. Something like [this](http://freekje.home.xs4all.nl/Wink/Wink_Tutorial_Capture.htm).

I looked for older questions and I saw that one of the few software that allows you to insert some text in the screencast is wink.

However it doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 11.10. When I try to start the screen cast all the wink Icon disappear from the sidebar and so I'm not able anymore to stop the registration.

Is there a way for fixing it? Otherwise, is there an alternative software?

Thanks!

Comment: which app you tried?

Comment: I tried with Wink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally record with **gtk-recordmydesktop** and then that output video I edit with openshot or pitivi (for me preferably openshot). Both of which can add text to a video. Of course not with the yellow background for the text in your link but at least some text somewhere you want and freeze the video for a moment so the viewer has time to read.

Answer (score 2):

GNOME 3 has a built in screen recording feature. Just press `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+R` to start and stop recording. The file will appear in your home folder named something like `shell-YYYYMMDD-1.webm`.